# Add return or remove to default statement IO

Tags: javascript, html, css, intersection-observer

I have a intersection observer that changes the header in different `font-color` and `background-color` depending when content is intersecting that has a `data-color` and `data-background` declared on its div/section.

When in a default state and nothing is declared on div/section the header should not change, but now it keeps its latest change and does not return to default. So my question is how to add a return/remove to default statement in current script? In the fiddle example the you see that the second div with nothing declared doesn't change back to the default header in this case black on green.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sva10hq2/)

```
* {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
box-sizing: border-box;
font-family: sans-serif;
}

.g-100vh {
height: 100vh
}

header {
  min-height: 50px;
  position: fixed;
  background-color: green;
  color: black;
  width: 100%;
}
```

**Intersection Observer**

```
  const header = document.querySelector('header');
  const sections = document.querySelectorAll('div');
  const config = {
    rootMargin: '0px',
    threshold: [0.05, 0.95]
  };

  const observer = new IntersectionObserver(function (entries, self) {
    entries.forEach(entry => {
      if (entry.isIntersecting) {
        if (entry.intersectionRatio > 0.95) {
          header.style.color = entry.target.dataset.color;
          header.style.background = entry.target.dataset.background;   
        } else {
      if (entry.target.getBoundingClientRect().top < 0 ) {
          header.style.color = entry.target.dataset.color;
          header.style.background = entry.target.dataset.background;
          }
        } 
      }
    });
  }, config);

  sections.forEach(section => {
    observer.observe(section);
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a condition to your code if the element has no color or background defined it returns to the default one;

Code changed:

```
header.style.color = entry.target.dataset.color !== undefined ? entry.target.dataset.color : "black";
header.style.background = entry.target.dataset.background !== undefined ? entry.target.dataset.background : "green";
```

Working Example:

```js
const header = document.querySelector('header');
const sections = document.querySelectorAll('div');
const config = {
  rootMargin: '0px',
  threshold: [.05, .95]
};

const observer = new IntersectionObserver(function (entries, self) {
  entries.forEach(entry => {
    if (entry.isIntersecting) {
      if (entry.intersectionRatio > 0.95) {
        header.style.color = entry.target.dataset.color !== undefined ? entry.target.dataset.color : "black";
        header.style.background = entry.target.dataset.background !== undefined ? entry.target.dataset.background : "green"; 
      } else {
        if (entry.target.getBoundingClientRect().top < 0 ) {
        header.style.color = entry.target.dataset.color !== undefined ? entry.target.dataset.color : "black";
        header.style.background = entry.target.dataset.background !== undefined ? entry.target.dataset.background : "green"; 
        }
      } 
    }
  });
}, config);

sections.forEach(section => {
  observer.observe(section);
});
```

```css
* {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
box-sizing: border-box;
font-family: sans-serif;
}

.g-100vh {
height: 100vh
}

header {
  min-height: 50px;
  position: fixed;
  background-color: green;
  color: black;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<header>
 <p>Header Content </p>
</header>
<div class="grid-30-span g-100vh" style="background-color:darkblue;" data-color="white" data-background="blue">
    <img 
    src="data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 1.414 1'%3E%3C/svg%3E"
    data-src="/images/example_darkblue.jpg" 
    class="lazyload"
    alt="<?php echo $title; ?>">
</div>

<div class="grid-30-span g-100vh" style="background-color:lightgrey;">
    <img 
    src="data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 1.414 1'%3E%3C/svg%3E"
    data-src="/images/example_lightgrey.jpg" 
    class="lazyload"
    alt="<?php echo $title; ?>">
</div>

<div class="grid-30-span g-100vh" style="background-color:darkblue;" data-color="white" data-background="blue">
    <img 
    src="data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 1.414 1'%3E%3C/svg%3E"
    data-src="/images/example_darkblue.jpg" 
    class="lazyload"
    alt="<?php echo $title; ?>">
</div>

<div class="grid-30-span g-100vh" style="background-color:lightgrey;" data-color="black" data-background="grey">
    <img 
    src="data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 1.414 1'%3E%3C/svg%3E"
    data-src="/images/example_lightgrey.jpg" 
    class="lazyload"
    alt="<?php echo $title; ?>">
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks works great! Just wondering, could it also be a remove data-color and data-background statement so it returns to the css class of the header instead of needing to declare it again on the dataset?